# unordered_map insertion crawls to a halt

Tags: c++, hash, hashmap, unordered-map

Basically, I have an unordered_map and trying to add to it sets of pairs... about 500,000 of them.  I've noticed that as I add pairs the insertion speed gets slower and slower until it finally stops all together.  Any thoughts as to why this might be or how to fix this?

Map definition:

```
std::tr1::unordered_map<std::pair<int, int>, int, pairHash> x_map ;
```

Hash function - note that for my case I don't have to worry about pair.first==pair.second, so I believe this hash function should be sufficient, correct me if am wrong:

```
class pairHash
        {
        public:
            size_t operator()(const std::pair<int, int> & v) const
            {
                return v.first ^ v.second ;
            }
        } ;
```

Method to add values to the unordered_map... trying to add about 200,000-500,000 pairs:

```
initialize_map( EndPoint**& arr, std::tr1::unordered_map<std::pair<int, int>, int, pairHash> &my_map, int size )
{
    for( int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++ )   // add initial overlapping pairs
    {
        if( i % 100 == 0 )
            std::cout << "checking particle: " << i << " maxsize: " << my_map.max_size() << std::endl ;
        int j = 1 ;
        while( arr[i]->isMin && i+j < size &&    // while ys is a min, and not end of array
              arr[i]->v_id != arr[i+j]->v_id )      // anything between min and max is a possible collision
        {
            if( !arr[i]->isEdge || !arr[i+j]->isEdge )
            {
                my_map[std::make_pair( std::min( arr[i]->v_id, arr[i+j]->v_id ),
                        std::max( arr[i]->v_id, arr[i+j]->v_id ) )] = 1 ;
            }

            j++ ;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:
I am actually adding closer to 50,000,000 pairs... just ran a test...

EDIT2:

Example output before it freezes, where count is the number of entries in the map.  I believe it is trying to rehash the map, but not sure why it is failing to do so and freezing the computer:

checking particle: 87500 count: 35430415 load factor: 0.988477

checking particle: 87600 count: 35470808 load factor: 0.989652

checking particle: 87700 count: 35511049 load factor: 0.990818

checking particle: 87800 count: 35555974 load factor: 0.992073

checking particle: 87900 count: 35595646 load factor: 0.993163

checking particle: 88000 count: 35642165 load factor: 0.994427

checking particle: 88100 count: 35679608 load factor: 0.995434

checking particle: 88200 count: 35721223 load factor: 0.996563

checking particle: 88300 count: 35760313 load factor: 0.997616

checking particle: 88400 count: 35799621 load factor: 0.9987

checking particle: 88500 count: 35833445 load factor: 0.999649

Answer (score 4):

It's probably best to stick with the Boost `hash_combine` solution for a better hash function:

```
template <class T>
inline void hash_combine(std::size_t & seed, const T & v)
{
  std::hash<T> hasher;
  seed ^= hasher(v) + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed << 6) + (seed >> 2);
}

namespace std
{
  template<typename S, typename T> struct hash< std::pair<S, T> >
  {
    inline std::size_t operator()(const std::pair<S, T> & v) const
    {
      std::size_t seed = 0;
      hash_combine(seed, v.first);
      hash_combine(seed, v.second);
      return seed;
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: Is it legal to add that specialization? Doesn't the standard library provide `hash` for `pair`s?

Comment: @k-ballo - no the standard library doesn't include a hash for pairs... sadly :)

Comment: Kerrek SB - assuming I am unable to use the boost library, how else would you do this?

Comment: @ElfsЯUs: What do you mean? There's no library dependence; I posted the full code! What's unclear?

Comment: Ah, my bad, yes you are right.  However, even with using your implementation for the hash function it freezes.  Once the load factor reaches .999 it seems to be rehashing the table, and then crashing.  Any thoughts on how to prevent this? (see edit for example output before it freezes up.)

Comment: Hi - I cannot at all reproduce a failure of `unordered_map` ... could you please post (perhaps as a separate question) a complete, minimal, self-contained example where 500,000 insertions cause the program to cease working?

Answer (score 1):

Try taking a look at unordered_map::load_factor().  The result of this call should ideally be < 1.0.  If it is over 1.0 then your hash function is probably dodgy.  You should use hash_combine instead of XOR-ing your pair.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `reserve()` to pre-allocate enough buckets for all your pairs? Adding so many pairs could be triggering many resizes (and rehashings).

The next thing I'd check is your hash function. It looks a bit suspect, and if you are getting lots of hash collisions you many be getting a bunch of overflow buckets that slow down the lookups for each insert - in which case you'd be better off with `std::map`. You could modify your code to store the hash of each pair and then check the number of unique hashed values you generate.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a reserve() function for tr1::unordered_map... do you mean rehash()?  It seems like these two functions might to something similar...